# facing issue with Lucene query search from different index_id (data stored in different folders) after upgrading Lucene 4.6 to 8.0

Tags: java, lucene

1. After Upgrading Lucene from 4.6 to 8, facing issues in the search process.
2. We are creating 5 different folders for indexing with different index id ( 5 folders from 5 different tables). During the search process, we will join all these data to display.  After upgrading we are facing issues in search data.
3. When we are applying the filter for different fields from different index_id. It is searching for only one field.
4. I am seeing a difference in the Join Query.

```
JoinUtil.createJoinQuery(fromField, false, toField, Query, srch, ScoreMode.None);  
Query formation with different versions:
Lucene 4.6.0:
TermsQuery{field=case.id}
fromQuery=+(history.attribute:SExtendedAttribute1)  
 +history.modifiedBy:3ff0000000000000  (different parameter) Lucene 8.0.0:
TermsQuery{field=case.idfromQuery=+(history.attribute:SExtendedAttribute1)  
 +history.modifiedBy:3ff0000000000000}

fromQuery=+(history.attribute:SExtendedAttribute1)  
 +history.modifiedBy:3ff0000000000000  (different parameter is also visible.)
```

Please Suggest to me, as new to Lucene unable to predict it.

1. I found changes in JoinUtil.createJoinQuery in Lucene-join.jar between two versions.
2. Query formation is different in both versions.

Query formation with different versions:

```
Lucene 4.6.0:
TermsQuery{field=case.id}
fromQuery=+(history.attribute:SExtendedAttribute1)  
+history.modifiedBy:3ff0000000000000  (different parameter) Lucene 8.0.0:
TermsQuery{field=case.idfromQuery=+(history.attribute:SExtendedAttribute1)  
 +history.modifiedBy:3ff0000000000000}

fromQuery=+(history.attribute:SExtendedAttribute1)  
 +history.modifiedBy:3ff0000000000000  (different parameter is also visible.)

JoinUtil.createJoinQuery(fromField, false, toField, Query, srch, ScoreMode.None);
```

after running Lucene Query it should apply the filter for different fields (data is in different folders).

Comment: actual filter condition
[Filter:
  condition: (&(case.caseType in (Scase))(case.sourceName in (SDEDUPLICATE))(&(history.attribute in (SExtendedAttribute1))(history.modifiedBy eq 3ff0000000000000)))
]

Comment: need to change custom Collector according to new changes.

Answer (score 0):

this issue got fixed after adding this doc value for a unique column through which we apply the join query. new SortedDocValuesField(fieldName, new BytesRef(value));